# Include submitted changelist from jenkins along with other changelists from perforce

Tags: build, jenkins, perforce

Is it possible to include submitted changelist to perforce(incrementing build number in build.xml after p4 sync the files) along with other changelists? Currently submitted changelist for incremented build number comes along with next build. So, suppose I am building #101 build and submitting changelist for the same so build email for this will not have this but next time while building #102 I see this changelist with other changelists. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant by

> "incrementing build number in build.xml"

but you can set the build display name to whatever you want via [Build Name Setter](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) plugin.

Personally I have it set to `${ENV,var="P4_CHANGELIST"}` for almost all jobs (since I prefer to see e.g. **120237** (Perforce changelist number) as the build name, instead of **#101** (buildNumber, just the sequential number of the build saying nothing to me).

So that you can set the build name to your newly submitted changelist number.

What about the "build email" and its contents - highly depends on what mechanism you use for email notifications. I use [Email Extension](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin which is flexible and you can manipulate message contents (e.g. adding a note about the newly submitted changelist).

Comment: I think he has the same question that I'm currently looking into - your build process updates a file with a new build number and checks it in, but you don't want that to count as a "change."  You want the adjust Jenkins/perforce plugin's sense of what the "last build" was to skip the version number file change.

Comment: Ah, I seem to get you. So, your build script performs the commit of _this_ build number into some file in your p4 depot, and you want this change to be listed in _this_ build **Changes**, right? - Well, this is kind of impossible if you do this AFTER the P4 sync is done. BUT, if you do this BEFORE the sync is done, I think you should be able to achieve this. You can try to use **Prepare an environment for the run** (**Environment Injector Plugin** - seem to be out-of-the-box feature) option in the **General** section, this happens exactly before SCM sync, just as you need.

Comment: I ended up making my build scripts look at the changelog file and seeing if there were a) no changelists or b) a single changelist with a specific title and author (to account for the build number bump later).  A little awkward, but works.